# Javascript: Is there a way to specify infinite input parameters for Parse.Promise.when?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, .when

Looking at the documentation for Parse.Promise.when (https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Promise.html#.when), currently, there are two ways of specifying it. The first is with comma separated input parameters for "when" and followed by comma separated inputs for the function in "then"

```
Parse.Promise.when(p1, p2, p3).then(function(r1, r2, r3) {
    console.log(r1);  // prints 1
    console.log(r2);  // prints 2
    console.log(r3);  // prints 3
  });
```

and the Second is with an array input for "when" followed by comma separated inputs for the function in "then."

```
  var promises = [p1, p2, p3];
  Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(r1, r2, r3) {
    console.log(r1);  // prints 1
    console.log(r2);  // prints 2
    console.log(r3);  // prints 3
  });
```

My question is: For the function inside "then," is there a easy way to specify an infinite amount of inputs without actually having to put in an infinite amount of inputs? In other words, is there a way to reproduce this in a simple way?

```
var promises = [p1, p2, p3];
      Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(r1, r2, r3,.............∞) {
        console.log(r1);  // prints 1
        console.log(r2);  // prints 2
        console.log(r3);  // prints 3
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        ∞
      });
```

I tried using the "arguments" variable but it does not work in this case. It seems I have to put in one by one the parameters r1,r2,r3...∞. Does anyone know a way around this? Please help

Comment: Can you show us the code where you tried using the `arguments` variable? I'm pretty sure that should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but there will be.

ECMAScript 6 features [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) which allow you to do this:

```
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(r1, r2, r3, ....rest) {
     console.log(r1); // prints 1
     console.log(rest); // an array with the rest of the parameters.
});
```

In EcmaScript 5 you need to use `arguments`:

```
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
     console.log(arguments[0]); // prints 1
     // prints 2 in the first iteration all the way to the last one
     for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
         console.log(arguments[i]); 
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks you! My mistake was inserting "arguments" for the parameter inside the anonymous function. Thank you!

Comment: @user3145336 glad I could help you solve your issue. To be fair `arguments` is really problematic in JS.